# PHP - mysqli_fetch_assoc, 2 results then into an array

Tags: php, mysql

```
$caballoganador = rand(1,9);
$selectganadores3 = array();
$arrayresultados = array();
$selectGanadores ="SELECT `usuario` from `jugadacaballo` WHERE `caballo` =' $caballoganador'";
$selectGanadores1 = mysqli_query($conn, $selectGanadores);
while($selectganadores2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($selectGanadores1)){
    $selectganadores3 = $selectganadores2['usuario'];
    array_push($arrayresultados,$selectganadores3);
}
```

Why the results are not pushing into the array? I'm new with Programming, sorry for my errors.

Comment: For one thing, there shouldn't be a space inside the first quote here `' $caballoganador'` and it does count as a character.

Comment: Your query probably isn't returning any results because of the space between the quote and your dollar sign. If you use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php), you'd eliminate quoting issues like this one.

Comment: It's also unknown as to what the origin and value of `$caballoganador` is.

Comment: Check the output of `print_r(mysqli_num_rows($selectGanadores1));`. You will get how many records are fetched.

Comment: You can simplify to `$arrayresultados[] = $selectganadores2['usuario'];`. The issue you're asking about is not clear though. What 2 results are you getting? What should you be getting

Comment: @user3783243 I should have 2 usernames because they have the winning horse, i recieved this  "user1user2" i cant use that result.

Comment: @RohitRasela Im getting "22

Comment: Did you try to debug `$selectganadores2['usuario']` Inside the loop?

Comment: @RohitRasela i get this when i use a var_dump                                       array(1) { ["usuario"]=> string(7) "apok9.9" } 
2array(1) { ["usuario"]=> string(8) "apokty99" }

Comment: Can you put only single statement `$arrayresultados[] = $selectganadores2['usuario'];` inside the loop and print `print_r($arrayresultados)` outside the loop? Only single statement inside while.

Comment: It sounds like you are pushing `$selectganadores2` to the array, not `$selectganadores3`. Are you sure this is your exact code? `va_dump($selectganadores2['usuario'])` gives back what?

Comment: @RohitRasela Omg i love you $arrayresultados[] = $selectganadores2['usuario']; this is the solution.

Comment: Can I add it to the answer?

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it with `$arrayresultados[]`

```
$caballoganador = rand(1,9);
$selectganadores3 = array();
$arrayresultados = array();
$selectGanadores ="SELECT `usuario` from `jugadacaballo` WHERE `caballo` ='$caballoganador'";
$selectGanadores1 = mysqli_query($conn, $selectGanadores);
 while($selectganadores2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($selectGanadores1)){
     $arrayresultados[] = $selectganadores2['usuario']; 
}
```